# Delete folder that contains thumbs.db

Tags: c#, windows-7

Sometimes I can't delete a folder, because it contains *thumbs.db*. I have a lot of folders (which contain images too) and I will need to move them to a different place and delete the original folder. But I am getting this error: the folder can't be deleted because "thumbs.db" is being used by another process.
Moving and deleting is made in c#, and right now it skips deleting the folders that have thumbs.db, which will result in a lot of empty folders. Is there a way to delete the folder even if it has that file?

Comment: AFAIK, thumbs.db files in win7 are stored somewhere in AppData and not in the each folder with images, aren't they?

Comment: Have you already tried to run your program as an administrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

am submitting my comment as an answer because it is much more readable this way:

You can switch off a creation of these files: 
in Registry Editor go to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer** 
and set **NoThumbnailCache** entry's value to 1.

If you don't have this entry , just create it (DWORD 32).

For Win 7 Ultimate/Professional version: 
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced**

**DisableThumbnailCache** (DWORD also)

To delete all already existing files create a batch file with the following content:

```
cd c:\

del /s /q thumbs.db
```

and run it **as administrator**

Answer (score 2):

### Find out who is locking

First thing you should do is finding what which process is holding a lock. You can use [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml) to find that out.

### If you can't kill, control or quit that process

You can mark files for deletion. They will get deleted at the next startup. Use PInvoke and call `MoveFileEx` passing null in as the destination.

You can use this for folders and files. Marking the folder for deletion should be enough.

This link has some sample code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, int dwFlags);

public const int MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT = 0x4;

MoveFileEx(filename, null, MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case simplest solution helped, however I am aware it is not going to help every time.

> 1. Close File Explorer (this should unlock file)
> 2. Open again and try to delete folder.

Answer (score 1):

When `Thumbs.db` is sitting in an otherwise empty folder (as in the case of the original question), deleting (of `Thumbs.db` and the folder) is often prevented by *WindowsExplorer*. In this case the following *manual actions* helped me every time so far, both on network and local drives:

1. Put a new jpg into the folder to force Windows to update the `Thumbs.db`.
2. In *WindowsExplorer* switch the view from *Details* to *Large icons*.
3. You can now delete the `Thumbs.db`, the new jpg and the folder itself.

I know that this is not a direct solution to your problem where you want to *programatically* delete those folders, but maybe this hint could push you in a good direction.

I don't want to adorn myself with borrowed plumes: the solution was taken from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b44e1129-17ec-479b-af89-7b407a53e085/cant-delete-folders-because-thumbsdb-is-in-use?forum=w7itprogeneral).

Answer (score 0):

In "Control panel" / "File Explorer Options" / View

- uncheck "Always show icons, never **thumbnails**"
- uncheck "Display the icon on **thumbnails**"

In file explorer menu View set **Tiles**.

For me now I could delete Thumbs.db from network drive e.g. **Z:\path\Thumbs.db**