# Can't delete Source Directory because of Thumbs.db file

Tags: c#, windows, copy, archive, robocopy

I created an application to archive a folder structure over the context menu to a specific location. The source folder need to be deleted after the copy process.

Now I have the following problem:
When I copy a folder with content which creates these "Thumbs.db" files, then I cannot delete/move the source folder, because these "Thumbs.db" files are in use by the explorer.

At the moment I use two Robocopy commands to archive.
This to archive all files and folders except these "Thumbs.db" files. This is needed because when I don't exclude these files first then wont work the whole copy process.

```
"Robocopy.exe " + '"' + spath + "\" \"" + ultpath + "\" /xf Thumbs.db /e /move /r: 1 /w: 1 /A-:RHSA /LOG:" + LOG + " /NFL
```

And this here to finally copy these "Thumbs.db" files.

```
"Robocopy.exe " + '"' + spath + "\" \"" + ultpath + "\" /e /move /r: 1 /w: 1 /LOG:" + LOG2 + " /NFL "
```

Disable the creation of these "Thumbs.db" files isn't a solution, because many of these files already exists. Furthermore this application is running on networkshares.

Is there a workaround or a solution to copy/delete/move/destroy these "Thumbs.db" files?

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767629/delete-folder-that-contains-thumbs-db

Comment: I am working in a business environment, so I can't just change registry keys.